# Use eloquent model in routes call back function gives error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Why cant i use Eloquent model in routes.php.

Like this

```
Route::get('image', function(){
    $user= [
        "image_name" => 'one'
    ];
    User::create($user);
});
```

I also tried `use App\Users;` and `namespace App`
It gives error.

Before I dive into controller i needed to check some things in routes itself.
How to get this work in the routes.php?

Comment: which error exactly?

Comment: class 'User' not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
use App\User;
```

to the top of `Routes.php`

Pay attention: `App\User`, not `App\Users`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use laravel 5 and higher you will need to use the model namespace.
Namespace is defined in model.
if your user model is located under `app folder`, than in model `User.php` you need to add (define its namespace)

```
namespace App;
```

And after call it

```
\App\User::method()
```

If you User model is located in

```
app/Models/User.php
```

The namespace should be

```
namespace App\Models;
```

And call it like so:

```
\App\Models\User::method()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this as well:

```
Route::get('image', function(){
    app('App\User')->create([
        "image_name" => 'one'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason  for down voting, if the sneaky down voter dares, then dare to explain, either I'll learn from you or I'll teach you :-)